# chef solo prepare command does not work

Tags: windows, chef-infra, knife-solo

I'm trying to using chef solo on a remote windows machine.
My "chef solo prepare" command works fine on a linux remote machine but on a windows remote machine with cygwin openssh running, when I run:

```
 knife solo prepare guy@64.231.175.27 -i ~/.ssh/my-rsa -V
```

I get the following error:

```
Bootstrapping Chef...
ERROR: SyntaxError: (eval):1: syntax error, unexpected $end
KnifeSolo::Bootstraps::
                   ^
```

I've already tested the ssh which works fine. Does anyone have a clue what I can do to fix this?

Comment: You're using this? http://matschaffer.github.io/knife-solo/ It doesn't sound like `knife solo prepare` is supported on Windows yet... the site only mentions preliminary support for Windows.

Comment: Yes, I am. But I just have to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

`knife solo prepare` does not work on Windows. You could wait until the maintainer can add Windows support or open a Pull Request on GitHub to add this functionality.